# MySQL Triggers on NDB cluster

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a trigger for a table within an ndb cluster. At first, I thought it was working perfect. After some time however, I realized the trigger was not executing on every INSERT like it should. I noticed the trigger was not on every node (show triggers was empty on all the db nodes except for one). We have a load balancer that balances equally all the mysql connections across the nodes, this is probably why it is not working correctly.

I thought the triggers would replicate. Do I need to create the trigger on every db node manually?

Comment: Never mind, found the answer buried deep:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

"The .TRN and .TRG files containing trigger definitions are not read by the NDB storage engine, and are not copied between Cluster nodes."

Comment: You should add it as an answer and accept it. It may help others.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to figure out how yesterday, finally did lol.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the answer buried deep: dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/… "The .TRN and .TRG files containing trigger definitions are not read by the NDB storage engine, and are not copied between Cluster nodes.

Had to create the triggers manually on each node.